# UserDefaults not saving when used in a framework

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults, swiftyuserdefaults

I have a framework that needs to save values locally, for that I chose UserDefaults.

However, the values are never saved, and the following read function always return `""` after restarting the app

```swift
class Preferences {
    let preferences : UserDefaults

    init (preferences : UserDefaults) {
        self.preferences = preferences
    }

    // Private Key
    func savePrivateKey(key : String) {
        writeString(value: key, key: privateKeyKey)
    }

    func readPrivateKey() -> String! {
        return readString(key: privateKeyKey)
    }

    private func readString(key : String) -> String? {
        if preferences.object(forKey: key) == nil {
            return "bananas"
        } else {
            return preferences.string(forKey: key)
        }
    }

    private func writeString(value : String, key : String) {
        preferences.set(value, forKey: key)
    }

    fileprivate let privateKeyKey = "privateKey"
}
```

Initialized with:

`let preferences = Preferences(preferences: UserDefaults.standard)`

I have tried:

- Simulator and physical Device
- Debug and Release
- UserDefaults and SwiftyUserDefaults

The strange thing is that this is saving the `Bool` values, but not the string ones.

I thought that this might be from not using correctly `UserDefaults`, but `SwiftyUserDefaults` gets the same result.

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly synchronize? (i.e. call `preferences.synchronize()` after writing? You should give it a try.

Comment: Yes, and that is deprecated, `-synchronize is deprecated and will be marked with the NS_DEPRECATED macro in a future release.`

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087085/nsuserdefaults-and-ios-framework-library

Comment: @CZ54 I have seen that before, but isn't that to be used in the case that I want default values for the SDK? In my case, when the SDK starts we have no values stored and no default values, so I thought that this wasn't the approach

Comment: @Vanethos You want share value across you app and the framework ?

Comment: also @CZ54 what is mentioned in that answer is already deprecated (`UserDefaults.register`)

Comment: @CZ54, no, I just want the framework to be able to store and read values. If the app needs to access those values, it will be by a method from the framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Foundation

public class AppDefaults {
    private let defaultStringKey = "DefaultString"
}

public extension AppDefaults {

    var defaultString: String? {
        get { return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: defaultStringKey) }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue?.description, forKey: defaultStringKey) }
    }

}
```

I suggest you make a separate file called something like AppDefaults etc. You can then access each default as such

```
var text = AppDefaults().defaultString
```

You can then overwrite it and it will save automatically using

```
AppDefaults().defaultString = "Bananas"
```

Comment: that is not the issue, the issue is that the preferences are not being saved correctly, so every time I use `UserDefaults.standard.string` it always gives out `""` as the value, even if I set the default as `bananas`

Comment: @Vanethos have you tried setting and trying to read UserDefaults using the method I've shown above?

From what you've shown the preferences isn't being initialised. You might need to show the full code to see what's going on. What's above looks like a much cleaner implementation.

Comment: @Vanethos I tested your updated code and did a 

  print(Preferences(preferences: UserDefaults.standard).readPrivateKey()) and i got Optional("bananas")

There must be something else affecting this..

Comment: as stated in the question, this code is used in a Framework. Is that an issue? @HJDavies

Comment: The framework defaults to using "bananas"? haha. What framework is this out of curiosity. I'd suggest using your own implementation to handle user defaults if this isn't working unless it's required to use the framework.

Comment: "There must be something else affecting this.." THANK YOU SO MUCH! This was just some stupid wrapper code that I was using and neglected to check. THANK YOU! @HJDavies

Comment: Haha glad to hear. It's always the smallest bits that mess up and cause hours of pain!